# Creating random CNF formulas prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, swi-prolog, logic-programming, conjunctive-normal-form

For my thesis, I am looking at specific properties of knowledge bases and how this affects argumentation tree sizes. I need a sat solver in prolog which I already have, but I also need an algorithm that creates random clauses.
k-SAT means clauses of precisely length k. For simplicity, I will set k to 3, max 4. I want to give K (amount of literals per clause) as a parameter to the program. So if I want a 3-sat, with 1000 clauses and 300 literals, then my program should create a knowledge base with 100 clauses of length 3 where all of those literals randomly have to be spread out with a certain ratio of negative ones (50/50 for simplicity). I want the output to look like this, Output: a set of clauses randomly created:

V1 :- V2, V3.

V2 :- -V3, -V4.

could somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Logtalk provides a user-extensible [`arbitrary`](https://logtalk.org/manuals/libraries/arbitrary.html) library and QuickCheck support in its [`lgtunit`](https://logtalk.org/manuals/devtools/lgtunit.html#quickcheck) developer tool. You can use both with [most Prolog systems](https://logtalk.org/download.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately, my coordinator wants me to write my own program.

Comment: You would still need to write the actual code that generates the arbitrary clauses with the exact format that you want (there's a default generator for arbitrary clauses but from your description you need finer control).

Comment: sorry, i was to quick to respond, but im not sure how to work with this, since i do not even understand how i would start with the program in prolog myself :(

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
random_knowledge_base(NumberOfClauses,
                      LiteralsPerClause,
                      AmountOfLiterals,
                      Ratio,
                      KnowledgeBase) :-
    length(KnowledgeBase, NumberOfClauses),
    maplist(random_clause(LiteralsPerClause, AmountOfLiterals, Ratio), KnowledgeBase).

random_clause(LiteralsPerClause, AmountOfLiterals, Ratio, Head :- Body) :-
    randseq(LiteralsPerClause, AmountOfLiterals, [Number|Numbers]),
    atom_concat(p, Number, Head),
    maplist(literal(Ratio), Numbers, Literals),
    comma_list(Body, Literals).

literal(Ratio, Number, Literal) :-
    atom_concat(p, Number, Proposition),
    (   maybe(Ratio)
    ->  Literal = Proposition
    ;   Literal = -Proposition ).
```

Example:

```
?- random_knowledge_base(5, 3, 9, 0.7, B).
B = [(p2 :- p5, -p6),  (p8 :- p3, p6),  (p9 :- p7, p2),  (p4 :- -p1, p6),  (p8 :- p1, p9)].
```

**Detailed explanation of the code**

- The ISO predicate [`atom_concat/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_concat/3) concatenates two atoms to form a third one:

```
?- atom_concat(p, 2, A).
A = p2.
```

- The predicate [maybe/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maybe/1) succeeds with probability *P* and fails with probability 1-*P*:

```
?- maybe(0.5).
true.

?- maybe(0.5).
false.
```

- A goal of the form [(Condition -> Then ; Else)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2) works as a conditional statement:

```
?- (maybe(0.5) -> writeln(positive) ; writeln(negative)).
negative
true.

?- (maybe(0.5) -> writeln(positive) ; writeln(negative)).
positive
true.
```

- Thus, for example, the goal `literal(0.5, 1, L)` randomly generates a literal `p1` or `-p1`:

```
?- literal(0.5, 1, L).
L = -p1.

?- literal(0.5, 1, L).
L = p1.
```

- To choose *K* unique random integers in the range 1..*M*, we can use [randseq/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=randseq/3). For *K* = 3 and *M* = 5, we have:

```
?- randseq(3, 5, Ns).
Ns = [4, 5, 2].

?- randseq(3, 5, Ns).
Ns = [1, 3, 2].
```

- To transform a list of *K* arbitrary integers into a list of *K* corresponding literals, we can use [maplist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3):

```
?- randseq(3, 5, Ns), maplist(literal(0.5), Ns, Ls).
Ns = [1, 3, 5],
Ls = [p1, p3, p5].
```

- The predicate [comma_list/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prolog_code%3Acomma_list/2) can be used to transform a list of literals into a conjunction:

```
?- randseq(3, 5, Ns), maplist(literal(0.5), Ns, Ls), comma_list(B, Ls).
Ns = [1, 5, 3],
Ls = [p1, p5, p3],
B =  (p1, p5, p3).

?- randseq(3, 5, Ns), maplist(literal(0.5), Ns, Ls), comma_list(B, Ls), C = (p3 :- B).
Ns = [1, 4, 2],
Ls = [-p1, p4, -p2],
B =  (-p1, p4, -p2),
C =  (p3 :- -p1, p4, -p2).
```

- Putting it all together, we have predicate `random_clause/4`:

```
?- random_clause(3, 4, 0.5, C).
C =  (p3 :- p4, -p2).

?- random_clause(3, 4, 0.5, C).
C =  (p1 :- -p5, p4).
```

To create a random knowledge base with, for example, 4 clauses:

```
?- length(KB, 4).
KB = [_, _, _, _].

?- length(KB, 4), maplist(random_clause(3,5,0.5), KB).
KB = [(p2 :-p1, -p3),  (p5 :-p2, p3),  (p3 :- -p4, p5),  (p3 :- -p1, p4)].
```

Or, using predicate `random_knwoledge_base/5`:

```
?- random_knowledge_base(4, 3, 5, 0.5, KB).
KB = [(p1 :- -p4, -p5),  (p2 :- p3, p4),  (p2 :-p3, -p5),  (p3 :- -p1, -p4)].
```

Comment: wow tnx, ill check it out! much appreciated!!

Comment: do you maybe have a small explanation for me, since i understand half of the code haha!

Comment: thank you, you are a true hero! and i have check marked it!! :)

Comment: hey! I have another question. I tried changing your code but I get a lot of errors, I do understand the code thoroughly but when i try to change the output into a list of lists instead of the clauses being in brackets i get an error that i cannot seem to fix. Is there a way to change the output to then eventually feed it to this sat-solver? thanks in advance :) the output should look like this --> ([[true-X,false-Y],[false-X,false-Y],[true-X,true-Z]],[X,Y,Z]). And this is a link to the sat solver --> staff.city.ac.uk/~jacob/solver/sat_solver.txt

Comment: @AmaSma Please post a new question specifying in detail what format you want the output to be, what code you have created and what errors you have got. That way it will be easier to clarify your doubt.

Comment: i have posted it, thanks for helping, i really appreciate it